How do windows work in Muggle Britain?
At the Beginning of the fifth book, Harry hides in the bushes outside the Dursley's living room, in order to hear the evening news, waiting for some hint of what Voledmort is up to.
When somebody does something in order to conduct his totally legitimate business, a bang is heard and Harry jumps up hitting his head on the open window:

A loud, echoing crack broke the sleepy silence like a gunshot; a cat streaked out from under a parked car and flew out of sight; a shriek, a bellowed oath, and the sound of breaking china came from the Dursleys’ living room, and as though Harry had been waiting for this signal, he jumped to his feet, at the same time pulling from the waistband of his jeans a thin wooden wand as if he were unsheathing a sword. But before he could draw himself up to full height, the top of his head collided with the Dursleys’ open window, and the resultant crash made Aunt Petunia scream even louder.
Harry felt as if his head had been split in two; eyes streaming, he swayed, trying to focus on the street and spot the source of the noise, but he had barely staggered upright again when two large purple hands reached through the open window and closed tightly around his throat.               (Order of the Phoenix, Chapter 1, Dudley Demented).

I've read the books a couple of times over the years, but something struck me as odd this time around, that I had never noticed before:
In order for Harry to hit his head by getting up the window must open outwards. I've only been to Britain a couple of times as a tourist - and that mainly meant London and a bit of the surrounding area - but the windows I encountered were similar to continental Europe in that they opened inwards. Which is only logical, as otherwise in order to close an open window one would have to lean far outside - not that bad on the ground floor, but nobody would want to do that higher up. Not mentioning cleaning them from the outside, which Petunia would certainly do, repeatedly. And if the windows slided upwards in their frames as they do in the US (if movies and TV shows are to be believed), hitting your head would be impossible.
The only other window mode would therefore be one that tilts around an axis in its center, either horizontally (around a vertical axis) or vertically (around a horizontal axis).
In the movie version of The Burrow the windows do indeed open outwards:

That could be a movie thing, or be a wizarding oddity - which the Dursleys certainly wouldn't want to have. At least it would probably be something anachronistic. The Ministry owl in the Order of the Phoenix movie flies in through something that appears to be the open conservatory door, so that doesn't help either.
So I'm guessing that if outward-opening windows are a British thing, they would most likely be found in older dwellings like the Burrow or Hogwarts

even though the windows there apparently do open inwards (in the movie version at least), and not in a modern suburb like Little Whinging. Further supporting this guess is the fact that in Chamber of Secrets the twins and Ron converse with Harry through the bars in front of Harry's bedroom window, which he wouldn't have been able to open if it opened outwardly to even allow for the rather whispery conversation, which they need, considering they need to prevent waking the Dursleys.
tl;dr How do British windows work? If they open inwards, how did Harry hit his head while outside? If they open outwards, how has Petunia not broken her neck cleaning their outside and how could Harry open his to talk to Ron and the twins in the Anglia when a bar would prevent it from being opened?

My front room windows open outwards. Anyone listening below them would hit their head if they stood up suddenly.

Typically windows are cleaned while closed, by a window cleaner with a ladder and/or a long brush.

I've never really thought about it, but now that I do, I can't remember ever being somewhere where the windows opened inwards! Yes you have to lean out a bit to close them - but not that far! Opening them inwards would mean you would lose space in the room, as well as there being a good chance you'd bang your head off it while just hanging out in the room. Do they usually open inwards where you're from?

@komodosp Yes all windows open inwards. My living room window is the widest, 147cm, so almost 5ft. If I were to push that outwards, I'd either have to have very long arms, or throw out a fishing rod to reel it back in. That window is of course closed almost all of the time except for cleaning and a smaller one next to it is used regularly. And yes, of course you could bang your head on an opened window, if somehow you missed the fact that it is open while working underneath it.

"So I'm guessing that if outward-opening windows are a British thing, they would most likely be found in older dwellings like the Burrow or Hogwarts" - this seems like an entirely invented correlation. New windows that open outwards are manufactured today and have been for many years. While it is in the US, I have family who own a house where all of the windows open outwards, and these windows are around 20 years old. You do not have to lean at all to open or close them, you simply turn the crank, as in the answer about casement windows.

There is a good chance that this was a casement window, which opens like a door, with a hinge on the side, often by a crank, to make it easier to open and close them from the inside.

Typically attached to its frame by one or more hinges, casement windows were the historical choice that came before sash windows in Britain. This was due to their simple yet elegant design, opening easily like a door but bringing more light into living spaces.

As to why you would have such a window that opens outwards, fire safety egress.

If there are no fire doors then egress through the windows at ground and first floor level is your alternative 'exit' / point of egress if there is a fire. The windows will need to open outward from habitable rooms (Bedrooms, Living Room, Dining etc).

Or, alternately, it's simply traditional.
YouTube video on the topic




Here is the website of a major UK window company. You will see that almost all the windows they show open are opening outward. https://www.anglianhome.co.uk/double-glazing-windows. Main exceptions are sash windows which slide vertically.

r/LegalAdviceUK is really not a reputable source

@OrangeDog: Fair enough. It's the closest I've found to a good statement about it, although I keep seeing people state it anecdotally as required.

Hmm... https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/1124733/Approved_Document_B__fire_safety__volume_1_-_Dwellings__2019_edition_incorporating_2020_and_2022_amendments.pdf isn't helpful.

N.B. "story" is the American spelling, implying American counting. In British it's "storey", but we'd call it the "second floor".

^_^ Guilty as charged. I live in Pittsburgh.

I'm in England. We had our windows replaced 6 years ago, and they all open outwards.

You corrected it wrong. Your quote explicitly says that the first floor (your second story) is a means of egress.

I stand corrected. Hopefully.

There are indeed plenty of windows that rotate in some way, either around a vertical or horizontal axis, resulting in half of the window being outside when opened. They are also called pivot windows.
Either one of them would cause you to bump your head if you were crouched below it and suddenly got up.
Examples


